# How to add Google AdSense to my Django blog project?

Tags: django, adsense, google-ads-script

I have a Django blog app. The Google Adsense said that the script is not found in my website, however I copied it. Thank you in advance.

I have a default.html which is extended to all the other html pages. It contains the header with login/logout and signup buttons, the logo, a welcoming message and most importantly the Google Ads scripts.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" property="og:description" content="These articles are about movies and created by users.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="seo, python, django, movies, articles, opinions, posts, users, actress, actor, hollywood, mainstream, film">
        <meta name="author" content="************">
        <!-- Google AdSense meta tag -->
        <meta name="google-adsense-account" content="ca-pub-************">
        <title>Articles</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="************" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">
        <!-- Google AdSense -->
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-************" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=************"></script>
        <script>
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());

                gtag('config', '************');
        </script>
        <!-- Google Acceptable-Ads Message -->
        <script async src="https://fundingchoicesmessages.google.com/i/pub-************?ers=1" nonce="************"></script><script nonce="************">(function() {function signalGooglefcPresent() {if (!window.frames['googlefcPresent']) {if (document.body) {const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); iframe.style = 'width: 0; height: 0; border: none; z-index: -1000; left: -1000px; top: -1000px;'; iframe.style.display = 'none'; iframe.name = 'googlefcPresent'; document.body.appendChild(iframe);} else {setTimeout(signalGooglefcPresent, 0);}}}signalGooglefcPresent();})();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}"><img alt="Logo" title="Logo" src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" /></a></h1>
            <nav class="create_logout_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="highlight" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><svg class="bi bi-facebook" fill="currentColor" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/></svg></a></li>
                    <li><a class="highlight" href="https://www.instagram.com/u/"><svg class="bi bi-instagram" fill="currentColor" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z"/></svg></a></li>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li>Hi, {{ user.username }}</li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:create' %}" class="highlight">Create new article</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The other html pages does not have head where I could put the AdSense script so I wanted to put in the default.html which loaded in every html pages. Here is an example how my other html pages build up:
It is a create article page.

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Article list</h1>
    <div class="articles_list">
        {% for article in items %}
        <div class="article_list">
            <a href="{% url 'articles:details' slug=article.slug %}">
            <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
            <p><img src="{{ article.thumb.url }}"/></p>
            <p>{{ article.short_desc }}</p></a>
            <p>{{ article.author }}, {{ article.date }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include 'articles/pagination.html' %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: adsbygoogle.js script looks correct. Do you have a link to your website to check how it is working in production?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau thank you very much for your comment. Yes, I have: www.moviefanblog.hu I didn't tested if it is reachable outside of Hungary, but I hope so. If you need anything else, just let me know. It would be part of my thesis, so I hope we can fix it.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I see ad request being sent from the tag. So not sure why AdSense is saying that the script is not found. Maybe you don't have enough users to generate some traffic from the site that triggers AdSense checks.